# How to Access method from a sub- abstract class

Tags: java, oop, abstract

I have the following hirarchy:

```
Interface s
Abstractclass1 implements s
Abstractclass2 extends Abstractclass1
```

in `Abstractclass2` there is a method unrecognized in `s`/`Abstractclass1` : `method2`
there is a test code that generate a new `s` object, i want to use `method2` on this object how do i access it?

Comment: Please paste in your actual code / errors, it's hard to tell from what you've typed.

Comment: You can't? Without downcasting s to Abstractclass2 you cannot access method2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not suppose to be able to call `method2` on an object with static type `Abstractclass1` (or `s`).

You can't call `bark()` if you have an `Animal` (who knows, it might be a `Cat` in runtime)

So, what to do? Either you change the static type to `Abstractclass2` or you do a downcast, as such: `((Abstractclass2) yourObject).method2`.

Comment: so I need to check the type first, assuming I did (and I did)- then how do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to typecast your instance of "S" to Abstractclass2.

e.g.

```
void myMethod(S myparam)
{
  if (myparam instanceof Abstractclass2)
  {
    ((Abstractclass2)myparam).method2();
  }
}
```